# How can you show/update template dynamically in HTML without using if:true?

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

Never mind. Its just a question to know about template. Any example also preferred with proper answer.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can use for:each

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multiple templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_render) (.html files), and choose one at runtime.

```
import TEMPLATE_1 from './template1.html';
import TEMPLATE_2 from './template2.html';

render() {
  if(someCondition) {
    return TEMPLATE_1;
  } else {
    render TEMPLATE_2;
  }
}
```

This replaces the entire component's template with the specified template. Note that `render` is a lifecycle hook; you must name it exactly this in order to use this technique.

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/i11PhgKk9u9yf7dzmBl2/src/app.html?p=stories).

You can also just use normal techniques to hide stuff:

```
renderedCallback() {
  const someElement = this.template.querySelector('div');
  if(someCondition) {
    someElement.classList.add('slds-hide');
  } else {
    someElement.classList.remove('slds-hide');
  }
}
```

The content will still be in the DOM, but won't be shown. This improve performance considerably. You can choose to do this any point after the first `render` call, but `renderedCallback` is the traditional place to do this. Again, this is a life cycle method, so you must make sure you exactly match the name. Note that it is also case-sensitive (i.e. `renderedcallback` won't work, it must be `renderedCallback`).